# Java regexp to match a list?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am using the pattern `"(?mis)^foo\\s+(\\d+)\\s+bar\\s+(\\d+)"` to search my input. What I really should be doing is to extract a list of one or more numbers at the end of the input line. i.e. given the input `"foo 10 bar 1 2 3"`, I should process 10 & 1 then 10 & 2, 10 & 3 and so on and so forth. I tried using "{1,}" with all kinds of variations at the end of the patten (and  `while (match.find()) {}` with no success.

How do I accomplish what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: whats d expected output

Comment: Where is the `0` coming from?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Sorry, my bad. A typo. Should have been 10 & 0, 10 &1 so on (10 being the first number in the input line)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to extract fixed part separately and all numbers separately:

```
(?mi)^foo\\s+(\\d+)\\s+bar((?:\\s+\\d+)*)$
```

Then on the `group(2)` just use:

```
String[] nums = matcher.group(2).split("\\s+");
```

to get all numbers after `bar`.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD1qT5/1)

Comment: That's a neat idea. Will do that. But just for my knowledge, any way to use just regex?